# Disable 302 Redirects in Firefox

Tags: firefox, redirection

I need to temporarily disable 302 redirects in Firefox. How can I do this? I tried going to `tools` > `options` > `advanced` > `general` > check `warn me when sites try to redirect or reload the page`, but that didn't work, 302 redirects are still followed. Is there anywhere in about:config that I can disable 302 redirects?

Comment: May be this will help you out.

[Link](http://superuser.com/questions/874819/prevent-automatic-redirects-in-firefox/874827#874827)

Answer (score 19):

call `about:config` and set `network.http.redirection-limit` to `0`. But you won't be able to access the moved page.

Comment: As I don't have Firefox installed right now, and for others benefit - What does changing this setting as advised do? Would hope that the user would get some warning (rather than a blank page) and / or a offer to load the next redirect.

Comment: @user66001 This setting is absolutely useless for end user. It is a limit of redirects before Firefox decides that it got into a redirect loop and stops following redirects. If you set it to 0 you'll get "Firefox decided that it got a redirect which will not end" error message immediately.

Comment: To anyone reading this answer: *strictly speaking*, this is the solution as OP asked: 302 redirects will *stop* being followed. But if you actually want _manual_ redirection, then it's not the solution you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I (and the OP) was looking for. To anyone not understanding how this setting can help: ask yourself how use the "allow cookies/images/stuff for this website" Firefox actions when you cannot access any page of that domain (always being redirected to another domain).

Comment: the user gets the "problem redrecting" error page. allowing the user to examine the headers and SSL certificate for the origin page etc.  setting '1' here instead of 0 allows single-stepping though the redirect chain (by clicking retry)

Comment: This did not work for me using Firefox Developer. I was able to change the setting, but it did not prevent the browser from following a 302 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to Firefox, but you could use the [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) debugging proxy, and set a breakpoint on the response. Or use [a script like](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Dev/ScriptSamples.asp) (I guess):

```
oSession.oResponse.headers.Remove("Location");
```

Comment: does this also block HTML `<meta http-equiv='location` redirects and javascript redirects?

Comment: No, but I guess one could write another rule to delete those from the HTML, using `oSession.utilDecodeResponse(); oSession.utilReplaceInResponse(...);`. I don't have Fiddler around to try.

Answer (score 0):

In "**Developer Tools > Debugger**"  in "**XHR Breakpoints**" there is the possibility to "**Pause on any URL**".

It's also possible to define other rules where redirections should be paused.

Then there are some buttons to step forward etc.